# Hash a Set of Integers from a Domain into a Set of Buckets

Tags: algorithm, hash

Say I have a set of integers ranging between 1-100. I will only have 5 of these integers drawn out of a hat. I want to then take those 5 integers and place them into 5 buckets guaranteed unique (without having to deduplicate or anything using something like [quadratic probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing)). Wondering how to do that.

For example, say I have these numbers (random from 1-100):

```
1 5 20 50 100
```

I then want to take those numbers and place them into these 5 buckets:

```
a b c d e
```

Using some hash function to accomplish it. For example, perhaps like this:

```
hash(1)   -> b
hash(5)   -> a
hash(20)  -> e
hash(50)  -> d
hash(100) -> c
```

Wondering how to write the hash function so that it takes a number `x` from a *domain* of numbers `D` and a set of numbers `D(X)` from that domain, and outputs 1 bucket `b` from the set of buckets `B`.

```
H : D(X) -> B
```

Next time around I might have 6 numbers between 1 and 1,000, going into 6 buckets. So then I would need a new hash function that works using those constraints (6 numbers, 6 buckets, range 1-1,000).

The goal is as few steps as possible.

Note: The hash function for this example won't take integers in a domain larger than 10,000 lets say, as well as the size of the set of integers limited to some small number too like 1,000.

---

#### Update

Basically I am trying to get this to happen:

```
// var domain = [1, 2, ..., 100]
// var set = [1, 5, 20, 50, 100]
// var buckets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

hash(1) // 2
hash(5) // 1
hash(20) // 5
hash(50) // 4
hash(100) // 3

function hash(integer) {
  if (integer == 1) return 2
  if (integer == 5) return 1
  if (integer == 20) return 5
  if (integer == 50) return 4
  if (integer == 100) return 3
}
```

But I don't know how to construct that hash function dynamically.

One solution (in JavaScript) would be to just create a map like this:

```
var map = {
  1: 2,
  5: 1,
  20: 5,
  50: 4,
  100: 3
}
```

But that's sort of cheating because the object in JavaScript is implemented as a hashtable underneath (or something like that). So I am looking for how to do this at a low level, just using basically what assembly gives you.

Pretty much, I want to do this:

```
           1                     
    5      |                     
    |      |                    20
    |      |             50     |
    |      |      100    |      |
[ slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5 ]
```

Where `1` is somehow "hashed" to go into that `slot2` in an array of size 5 (that slot is arbitrary for this example), etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you only looking to hash these six values into separate buckets, or are you looking for a function that will work on *any* set of numbers, but with the proviso that the first six numbers will always have distinct hash values?

Comment: I am looking to hash _any_ set of integers in a set of size `n` into equal number of buckets (a set of size `n`), where the integers come from some bounded domain. The 5 and 6 values were just examples to demonstrate how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the domain of your integer values is the range from 0 to n-1, and you want the set of values [x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>k-1</sub>] to map to values from 0 to k-1.

Create an array of n values containing the numbers from 0 to k-1 in roughly equal amounts, for example [a<sub>0</sub> = 0, a<sub>1</sub> = 1, ..., a<sub>k</sub> = 0, ..., a<sub>n</sub> = n%k].

Then for each of the k values in the initial set (x<sub>i</sub>, where i = 0 .. k-1), change the k-th element of this array to i, either by direct assignment or by swapping with a value from elsewhere (taking care not to clobber a value set for a previous element of the initial set).

Then to hash a value y, just fetch the y-th value from this array.

---

#### DEMO

Here's a Javascript demo that basically implements the above algorithm, except that instead of pre-filling the array with values from 0 to k-1, it first inserts the hash values for the selected items, then fills the remaining items with the repeating sequence of numbers from 0 to k-1. You will probably get better collision resistance by using a random sequence instead of incrementing values, but I hope you get the picture.

```js
var hash_array;

function generate_hash() {
  var i, j, k;
  var v = document.getElementById;
  var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
  // Create a new hash lookup table
  hash_array = Array(n);
  // Initialize every value to -1
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) hash_array[i] = -1;
  // Map the given values to the first k hash buckets
  var initial_values = document.getElementById("init").value.split(/ +/);
  k = initial_values.length;
  for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
    hash_array[initial_values[i]] = i;
  }
  // Fill the remaining buckets with values from 0 to k-1
  // This could be done by selecting values randomly, but
  // here we're just cycling through the values from 0 to k-1
  for (i=j=0; i<hash_array.length; i++) {
    if (hash_array[i] == -1) {
      hash_array[i] = j;
      j = (j + 1) % k;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("gen").innerHTML = "Hash lookup table:<br>" + hash_array.join(", ");
}
```

```html
<h2>Demo</h2>
<p>Creating a hash function that works on integer values  less than <i>n</i>. What is the value of <i>n</i>?<br>
<input type="number" id="n" min="6" max="100" value="20"/></p>
<p>Enter a few different values separated by spaces. These will hash to the first buckets<br/>
<input type="text" size="40" id="init" value="2 3 5 6 9"/></p>
<p id="gen"><button onclick="generate_hash(); return false">Generate hash table</button></p>
```

Comment: This sounds interesting! Trying to follow. The first paragraph I'm mostly following. So we have `array.length == 100` let's say, and in it are values `1 2 3 4 5` (if bucket size is 5), so like `[1, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 2, ...]`, somehow generated and evenly spaced. Then just change the kth element of the array to i. So `[...,i=20,value=5,...,i=50,value=4,...]`. Something like that. Hmm. Not sure why the randomly spaced numbers. Not 100% sure yet I understand, but it seems like what I was looking for! Thank you. Maybe if you could add an example that would help :)

Comment: Not sure why this: "Create an array of n values containing the numbers from 0 to k-1 in roughly equal amounts, for example [a0 = 0, a1 = 1, ..., ak = 0, ..., an = n%k]."

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

1. Create a **set of bucket IDs** and populate it ahead of hashing (assumption here is that set guarantees uniqueness). This means that you have to know in advance how many buckets you want.
2. For each **element** from the **input set** calculate `hash(element) modulo bucketIds.size` to find index of the next ID to use.
3. Remove the resulting bucket ID from the set of bucked IDs
4. Repeat (until you are done or the set of IDs is exhausted)

[Feel free to inspect the noddy implementation in JS using arrays](https://runkit.com/embed/xnvyp5enlxwo) (Node8).

Comment: So for example, (1) I would just make bucket IDs incremented from 1. So if I have 5 numbers, buckets `1 2 3 4 5`. Then for (2) not sure what the `hash` is. Then (3) remove the bucket ID we hashed to, so now lets say we have `1 2 3 4`. Then not sure how I would use the hash function once generated. Not quite sure I'm following, maybe if you could post an example that would help me better follow along.

Comment: added example in JS

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a function that's not a straight map, you could also experiment with [Polynomial Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).

Here's a JavaScript example using some [free code](https://arachnoid.com/polysolve/) under the GNU license.

```js
/***************************************************************************
 *   Copyright (C) 2018 by Paul Lutus                                      *
 *   lutusp@arachnoid.com                                                  *
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,       *
 *   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of        *
 *   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the         *
 *   GNU General Public License for more details.                          *
 *                                                                         *
 *   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License     *
 *   along with this program; if not, write to the                         *
 *   Free Software Foundation, Inc.,                                       *
 *   59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.             *
 ***************************************************************************/

// classic Gauss-Jordan matrix manipulation functions

var gj = gj || {}

gj.divide = function(A,  i,  j,  m) {
  for (var q = j + 1; q < m; q++) {
    A[i][q] /= A[i][j];
  }
  A[i][j] = 1;
}

gj.eliminate = function(A, i, j, n, m) {
  for (var k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    if (k != i && A[k][j] != 0) {
      for (var q = j + 1; q < m; q++) {
        A[k][q] -= A[k][j] * A[i][q];
      }
      A[k][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

gj.echelonize = function(A) {
  var n = A.length;
  var m = A[0].length;
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var k;
  var swap;
  while (i < n && j < m) {
    //look for non-zero entries in col j at or below row i
    k = i;
    while (k < n && A[k][j] == 0) {
      k++;
    }
    // if an entry is found at row k
    if (k < n) {
      //  if k is not i, then swap row i with row k
      if (k != i) {
        swap = A[i];
        A[i] = A[k];
        A[k] = swap;
      }
      // if A[i][j] is != 1, divide row i by A[i][j]
      if (A[i][j] != 1) {
        gj.divide(A, i, j, m);
      }
      // eliminate all other non-zero entries
      gj.eliminate(A, i, j, n, m);
      i++;
    }
    j++;
  }
}

// a simple data class

function Pair(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

Pair.prototype.toString = function() {return x + ',' + y};

// matrix functions

var matf = matf || {}

// a weak substitue for printf()

matf.number_format = function(n,p,w) {
  s = n.toExponential(p);
  while(s.length < w) {
    s = ' ' + s;
  }
  return s;
}

// produce a single y result for a given x

matf.regress = function(x, terms) {
  var y = 0;
  var m = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < terms.length;i++) {
    y += terms[i] * m;
    m *= x;
  }
  return y;
}

// compute correlation coefficient

matf.corr_coeff = function(data, terms) {
  var r = 0;
  var n = data.length;
  var sx = 0;
  var sx2 = 0, sy = 0, sy2 = 0, sxy = 0;
  var x, y;
  for (var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
    pr = data[i];
    var x = matf.regress(pr.x, terms);
    var y = pr.y;
    sx += x;
    sy += y;
    sxy += x * y;
    sx2 += x * x;
    sy2 += y * y;
  }
  var div = Math.sqrt((sx2 - (sx * sx) / n) * (sy2 - (sy * sy) / n));
  if (div != 0) {
    r = Math.pow((sxy - (sx * sy) / n) / div, 2);
  }
  return r;
}

// compute standard error

matf.std_error = function(data, terms) {
  var  r = 0;
  var  n = data.length;
  if (n > 2) {
    var a = 0;
    for (var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
      pr = data[i];
      a += Math.pow((matf.regress(pr.x, terms) - pr.y), 2);
    }
    r = Math.sqrt(a / (n - 2));
  }
  return r;
}


// create regression coefficients
// for provided data set
// data = pair array
// p = polynomial degree

matf.compute_coefficients = function(data,  p) {
  p += 1;
  var n = data.length;
  var r, c;
  var rs = 2 * p - 1;
  //
  // by request: read each datum only once
  // not the most efficient processing method
  // but required if the data set is huge
  //
  // create square matrix with added RH column
  m = Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    mm = Array();
    for (var j = 0; j <= p; j++) {
      mm[j] = 0;
    }
    m[i] = mm;
  }
  //double[][] m = new double[p][p + 1];
  // create array of precalculated matrix data
  mpc = Array();
  for(var i = 0;i < rs;i++) {
    mpc[i] = 0;
  }
  mpc[0] = n;
  for (var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
    pr = data[i];
    // process precalculation array
    for (r = 1; r < rs; r++) {
      mpc[r] += Math.pow(pr.x, r);
    }
    // process RH column cells
    m[0][p] += pr.y;
    for (r = 1; r < p; r++) {
      m[r][p] += Math.pow(pr.x, r) * pr.y;
    }
  }
  // populate square matrix section
  for (r = 0; r < p; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < p; c++) {
      m[r][c] = mpc[r + c];
    }
  }
  // reduce matrix
  gj.echelonize(m);
  // extract result column
  terms = Array();
  for (var i = 0;i < m.length;i++) {
    mc = m[i];
    terms[i] = mc[p];
  }
  return terms;
}

// test the system using known data

matf.test = function() {
  var xd = [-1,0,1,2,3,5,7,9];
  var yd = [-1,3,2.5,5,4,2,5,4];
  
  data = Array();
  
  for(var i = 0;i < xd.length;i++) {
    data[i] = new Pair(xd[i],yd[i]);
  }
  
  terms = compute_coefficients(data,6);
  
  var prec = 16;
  
  var width = 24;
  
  for(var i = 0;i < terms.length;i++) {
    print(number_format(terms[i],prec,width) + ' * x^' + i);
  }
  
  cc = corr_coeff(data,terms);
  
  print ('cc = ' + number_format(cc,prec,width));
  
  se = std_error(data,terms);
  
  print('se = ' + number_format(se,prec,width));
}

//test();

// "data" is an array of Pair(x,y) data
// p = polynomial degree

matf.process_data = function(data,p) {
  var terms = matf.compute_coefficients(data,p);
  var cc = matf.corr_coeff(data,terms);
  var se = matf.std_error(data,terms);
  return [terms,cc,se];
}

/**** END Paul Lutus' code ****/


function f(cs, x){
  let n = cs.length - 1;
  let result = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<cs.length; i++)
    result += cs[i] * Math.pow(x, i);
  return result;
}

var data = [[1,1], [5,2], [20,3], [50,4], [100,5]];
var xy_data = []

for (let i of data)
  xy_data.push(new Pair(i[0], i[1]));

var result = matf.process_data(xy_data, xy_data.length - 1);

for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++)
  console.log(data[i][0], f(result[0], data[i][0]));
```